# One to Many in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a model in which a Firm has a status. This means there are two tables:

1. Firm
2. FirmStatus

I have this defined in my project like this:

```
class FirmStatus extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'firm_statuses';

    protected $primaryKey = 'firm_status_id';

    protected $fillable = array('firm_status_id', 'name');
}



class Firm extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'firms';

    protected $primaryKey = 'firm_id';

    protected $fillable = array('name', 'firm_status_id');

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('User', 'firm_id', 'firm_id');
    }

    public function firm_status()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('FirmStatus', 'firm_status_id');
    }
}
```

But I can't seem to get this to work, no matter what way I try to access the FirmStatus on the Firm it just doesn't work?

In my controller I have this code:

```
        $firm = Firm::find($id);
    $firmClassifications = DB::table('firm_classifications')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->lists('name','firm_classification_id');

    return var_dump($firm);
```

which returns this:

```
object(Firm)[243]
  protected 'table' => string 'firms' (length=5)
  protected 'primaryKey' => string 'firm_id' (length=7)
  protected 'fillable' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string 'name' (length=4)
      1 => string 'firm_classification_id' (length=22)
      2 => string 'fca_number' (length=10)
      3 => string 'question_number_passed_on' (length=25)
      4 => string 'firm_status_id' (length=14)
  protected 'connection' => null
  protected 'perPage' => int 15
  public 'incrementing' => boolean true
  public 'timestamps' => boolean true
  protected 'attributes' => 
    array (size=7)
      'firm_id' => int 8
      'name' => string 'siofds4' (length=7)
      'fca_number' => string '' (length=0)
      'firm_classification_id' => int 1
      'created_at' => string '2014-09-08 11:06:17' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2014-09-08 12:24:23' (length=19)
      'firm_status_id' => int 2
  protected 'original' => 
    array (size=7)
      'firm_id' => int 8
      'name' => string 'siofds4' (length=7)
      'fca_number' => string '' (length=0)
      'firm_classification_id' => int 1
      'created_at' => string '2014-09-08 11:06:17' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2014-09-08 12:24:23' (length=19)
      'firm_status_id' => int 2
  protected 'relations' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'hidden' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'visible' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'appends' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'guarded' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '*' (length=1)
  protected 'dates' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'touches' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'observables' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'with' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'morphClass' => null
  public 'exists' => boolean true
```

I am expecting that $firm->firm_status (method call or not, whichever way will work) will allow me to access the specified firm status, but $firm->firm_status results in null.

Comment: A note: A primary key should not be user-editable; it should be removed from the FirmStatus `fillable` array to avoid unexpected behavior.

Comment: Good point! This will be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you won't see anything in `var_dump($firm)` result unless you load the relation.

Next thing - Eloquent requires you to use `camelCased` methods for relations, if you want to work with `dynamic methods` (call `$model->relation`).

So you need:

```
public function firmStatus()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('FirmStatus', 'firm_status_id');
}
```

then you can access it:

```
$firm->firmStatus; // FirmStatus model | null
$firm->firm_status; // this will be translated to firmStatus anyway, but not other way around
```

and to view it in your call:

```
$firm = Firm::with('firmStatus')->first();
var_dump($firm);
// but better use toArray(), since it's easier to read
dd($firm->toArray());
```

Comment: This has got it! Thank you. Thought I had to use firm_status, not firmStatus.

Answer (score 0):

If a firm can have a single status, use `hasOne()` instead of `belongsTo()`:

```
class Firm extends Eloquent {
    public function firm_status()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('FirmStatus', 'firm_status_id', 'firm_status_id');
    }
}
```

If you need to query all of the firms with a given status, add the inverse relationship to `FirmStatus`:

```
class FirmStatus extends Eloquent {
    public function firm()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Firm', 'firm_status_id', 'firm_status_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: This still isn't working! I have this working in another part of the model but it just doesn't work in this instance.

Comment: Will you define the behavior that you see? What do you expect to happen, and what is happening instead? What error messages do you receive?

Comment: I receive no error message. I've added some more detail onto the original question.

Comment: Your model is recognizing the firm_status relationship, because `'firm_status_id' => int 2 `. I noticed that I defined the inverse relationship incorrectly: `public function firm_status()` should be `public function firm()`. Will you let me know what happens when you make that change?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins You're wrong. `hasOne` is the other way around, you can't replace it with `belongsTo`. First requires FK on the other model, while latter needs FK to be on the calling model.